# Is there a way of solving this probability question without using the survival characteristic of a geometric random variable?

Tags: probability

I have the following problem, and the author presents the solution by using the survival characteristic of a geometric random variable:

[image]

However, I am not very familiar with this method and was wondering if it could be approached in a different way.

We desire $$E[X | Y = 5] = \sum_x x P[X = x | Y = 5] = \sum_x x \frac{P[X = x, Y = 5]}{P[Y = 5]}.$$

But $P[X = 1, Y = 5] = P[X = 2, Y = 5] = P[X = 3, Y = 5] = P[X = 4, Y = 5] = 0,$ because it is not possible to roll a 6 within 1-4 rolls and have the first even number occur on the 5th roll.

Now I will try thinking about the case of $(X = 5, Y = 5)$. So we require that we roll odd numbers for the first 4 rolls, and a 6 on the 5th roll. Hence: $P[X = 5, Y = 5] = (\frac{1}{2})^4(\frac{1}{6}).$

Next, consider $P[X = 6, Y = 5].$ We need to roll odd numbers for the first 4 rolls, an even number that is not a 6 on the 5th roll, and a 6 on the 6th roll. Then $P[X = 6, Y = 5] = (\frac{1}{2})^4(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{6}).$

After one more case, I think we can generalize. For $P[X = 7, Y = 5],$ we need an odd number for the first 4 rolls, a non-6 even number on the 5th roll, a non-6 number on the 6th roll, and a 6 on the 7th roll. Hence $P[X = 7, Y = 5] = (\frac{1}{2})^4(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{1}{6}).$

In general, for $x \geq 6$, $P[X = x, Y = 5] = (\frac{1}{2})^4(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{5}{6})^{(x - 6)}(\frac{1}{6}).$

Now from here I am unsure how to use this to calculate the expected value. I know that re-indexing we can get my probability function to look like a geometric series, but when we calculate expected value, we will multiply this series by x, which changes things.

Comment: In what way does it change anything?  $\sum_{x=6}^\infty \alpha x r^{x-6} = \alpha r^{-6} \sum_{x=6}^\infty x r^x$.  Use your formulas to simplify $\sum x r^x$ (noting that the limits are different than normal)  (normally $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x (1-p)^{x}p = \frac{1}{p}$)

Comment: Please read tag summaries before using tags. This is not what the [tag:geometric-probability] tag is for.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to recognize that the rolls of the die are memoryless.  Ordinarily, we have $E(X) = 6$.  When we see that $Y = 5$, there is a $1/3$ probability (since there are three even numbers, only one of which is $6$) that $X = 5$ also; otherwise, with $2/3$ probability, we have to roll another six times on average to get a $6$, and $E(X) = 5+6 = 11$.  Thus, overall, $E(X) = (5)(1/3)+(11)(2/3) = 27/3 = 9$.